# Send xml as input parameter in asmx web service

Tags: c#, asmx

I have a asmx web service with XML document as input parameter..like this...

```
public System.Xml.XmlDocument Load_DOK(System.Xml.XmlDocument XmlDoc) 
{
   //some irrelevant code....
}
```

Now for test I made a Form with button and made local service reference...I want to call web serivce and pass the XML as input parameter...

Here is the code...but I think it's wrong..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load XML document
            string XmlFilePath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\XPMUser\\Desktop\\STC-ovi\\STC_1.xml";
            XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDoc.Load(XmlFilePath);

            //Call web serivce and pass the XML as input parametar - > THIS PART IS WRONG I THINK!!!!
            TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.Load_DOKRequestBody req = new TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.Load_DOKRequestBody();
            TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.Load_DOKResponseBody resp = new TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.Load_DOKResponseBody();

            TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.PrimatServiceSoapClient WS = new TEST_FORMA.PrimatService.PrimatServiceSoapClient();

            resp = WS.Load_DOK(XmlDoc);

        }
```

In object browser i have this components

```
Load_DOKRequest
Load_DOKRequestBody
Load_DOKResponse
Load_DOKResponseBody
```

And when I execute the code above I get the message... "The method or operation is not implemented."

I think the above web service call is totally wrong...

Answer (score 0):

When i try to send a XmlDocument to ASMX webservice, the following error has thrown:

> cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'

When i send XElement to the ASMX webservice instead of XmlDocument, the method received the XML correctly.

```
ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient webservice = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
webservice.Load_DOK(new XElement("test"));
```

And the webservice method:

```
[WebMethod]
public System.Xml.XmlDocument Load_DOK(System.Xml.XmlDocument XmlDoc)
{
    return null;
}
```